# How do I close a socket with timeout of 2 seconds without data?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to invoke socket like this:

```
socket.end();
```

I want to achieve something like this after waiting for 2 seconds and not receiving data:

```
socket.on('data', function(data){});
```

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function socketEnd(){ socket.end(); }
var timeout = setTimeout(socketEnd, 2000);
socket.on('data', function(data){
    # got data, delay the timeout
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(socketEnd, 2000);
});
```